# Kotlin Multiplatform Library iosApp Run Configuration

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm developing the Kotlin Multiplatform Library, already written the `androidMain`, `commonMain` and `iosMain`. Now to test the written code on actual android and ios device I have added **example** package inside the root folder and created the new KMP project inside it where I can be able to showcase the my KMP library usage to community.

To link the example project with my library I've added below lines in library `settings.gradle.kts` file :

```
include(":example:kmp:androidApp")
include(":example:kmp:iosApp")
include(":example:kmp:shared")
```

After syncing the project I can see the `androidApp` run configuration to run and test the library code on device but not able to see `iosApp` run configuration to run the app on ios device.

[image]

Any help or lead will be appreciated.

Comment: The iOS configuration is only available on a Mac machine. Are you using a Mac machine?

Comment: @AtickFaisal Yes I'm using Mac system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you should not be able to see the `iosApp` configuration and run from Android Studio unless you have the [Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14936-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile) installed in your IDE. So make sure you have the correct compatible version installed.

Second thing is generally we add a new Multiplatform library module in an existing KMM project. We add the library functionality in this new module. Then we add the library module to the example project to demonstrate. You can do this by adding this to your example `build.gradle.kts` file (replace `library` with your library module name):

```
implementation(project(":library"))
```

So basically the KMP shared module of the example project and the library KMP module stays in the same hierarchy level with the root directory of the project. In your case, you created an `example` directory inside which the sample KMP project has been added. That might be the reason why Android Studio is unable to find the run configuration for iosApp.

You can try creating an **iosApp** run configuration manually (considering you have the KMM plugin installed) from `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog of Studio. Make sure the `Xcode project file` is pointing to: `../iosApp/iosApp.xcodeproj` file of your sample or example project. Also enter the other details like project `scheme`, `configuration` and `execution target`.

Also in the `settings.gradle.kts` file, you can just add (assuming your example and library modules are in the project root):

```
include(":example")
include(":library")
```

Comment: Thanks @Carshtokky for your detailed answer. I make it able to run ios by creating the run configuration for ios app as suggested by you.